# How to open holes in plastic electrical junction box

Tags: junction

How am I supposed to open the holes for the cables in a junction box like the one shown in the picture below?

[image: junction box]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I'm in Cyprus..

Answer (score 2):

I would use a sharp knife, a so called utility knife, if I had one handy, but would try my moderately well sharpened pocket knife if that was all I had.

**EDIT** It *may be* that all one has to do is to pierce a "ring" with a knife or even a flat blade screwdriver and then pulling propagates the tear as the inside is pulled out.

**EDIT2** The fact that the ring feature is convex suggests that the designers envisioned the removal could be with a slicing action with a blade parallel to the plane of the rings. For a right handed person I could imagine holding the box with the left hand with the inside of the left forearm braced against the chest.

The knife would be held in the right hand (cutting edge toward the thumb) with the right elbow braced against the person's ribs. The cut would be made by pulling the knife so that in the event of a slip the right forearm would contact the chest and stop the movement of the knife. After slicing 90 deg the box would be rotated 90 deg to continue the cut . . .

**Alternatively**, the box could be held down on a flat surface and the knife held with the cutting edge away from the thumb. The removal would be with a slicing action from above then the box flipped over for slicing the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a step drill bit similar to this one.  It will allow you to drill whatever size hole you need for the appropriate size connector.

[Cheap Harbor Freight Bit](https://m.harborfreight.com/2-piece-titanium-nitride-coated-high-speed-steel-step-drills-96275.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, you make sure this thing is actually certified for use in mains wiring.  If it came from ebay, amazon or alibaba/aliexpress, it's not.

Then, you obey the labeling and instructions that come with it.  It can't pass certification without instructions, because certification isn't for all uses, only for the methods of use described in the instructions.

If you improvise, that will get you written up by an inspector and you'll have to redo the work.

Regardless, any wire entry into a box requires a strain relief clamp, mainly to protect the wire from damage from the box edge, ***unless*** the labeling and instructions tell you otherwise.

> Which they would do, if the box had been designed, tested and certified to work that way.